# "No Socket Available" - Wifi Shield on Arduino

Tags: sockets, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have an LDR/Photocell which sends a value 1 or 0 (depending on the value) to a text file on my web address. The code works for a few seconds then prints out `No Socket available`.

Any help will be appreciated; code below.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

int LDR = A0;
int LED = 11;
char ssid[] = "SSID";
char password[] = "password";
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;


char server[] = "www.example.com";
int value;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LDR, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  connectWifi();
  printWifiStatus();
  // postData();
}

void loop() {
  value = analogRead(LDR);
  postData();

  delay(10000);
}

void connectWifi() {
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    delay(500);
  }
}

void printWifiStatus() {
  // Print the SSID of the network you're attached to
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // Print your WiFi shield's IP address
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // Print the received signal strength
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}

void postData() {
  WiFiClient client;
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("Connecting...");
    if (value > 350) {
      Serial.println("0");
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
      String data = "value=0";
      client.print("GET /example/client.php?");
      client.print(data);
      client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
      client.println("Host: www.example.com");
      client.println("Connection: close");
      client.println(); client.println();
      //client.stop();
    } else {
      Serial.println("1");
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
      String data = "value=1";
      client.print("GET /example/client.php?");
      client.print(data);
      client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
      client.println("Host: www.example.com");
      client.println("Connection: close");
      client.println(); client.println();
      //client.stop();
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("Connection failed");
    client.stop();
  }

}
```

Output:

```
Attempting to connect to SSID
SSID: SSID
IP Address: 255.255.255.255
signal strength (RSSI):-47 dBm
Connecting...
1
Connecting...
0
Connecting...
0
Connecting...
0
No Socket available
Connection failed
No Socket available
Connection failed
No Socket available
Connection failed
No Socket available
```

Actual web address omitted.

Comment: You already asked [this on Arduino Stack Exchange](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/36496/). Why a new account?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, try not use "delay()" and your are calling this function "`postData()`" every 0,5 seconds. Try use the `millis()` function to do the timer thing, like this:

```
unsigned long timerBefore = 0;
const int timer = 1000; //1 second
```

now inside your `loop()`

```
unsigned long timerNow=millis();
if((unsigned long)(timerNow-timerBefore)>=timer){
   postData();
   timerBefore=millis();
}
```

that code i'll not "pause" your microcontroller and will call that function every one second.